# How to make responsive image placeholders the size and aspect ratio of the final image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple responsive online image gallery to scroll vertically. I'd like to show image placeholders during the loading time of the image. I'm struggling giving the image placeholders the size and aspect ratio of the final image to display.

I'm using a 1px image in the `src` attribute that I will replace with the actual image lazily as the user scrolls the page. I set the `width` and `height` attributes of the final image in the `img` tag, with `width: 100%` and `height: auto` in the css but I end up with small squares. Removing `height: auto` shows the correct height but I lose the aspect ratio on small screens. I have also tried `object-fit: contain` without success.

How can I make the image placeholders with right size and aspect ratio that works both on large and small screens?

Here is an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 6%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

body, figure {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
</head>
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="slideshow">
        <figure>
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Jean-Leon_Gerome_Pollice_Verso.jpg" height="2425" width="1630">
          <figcaption>1</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c5/Jean-Leon_Gerome_Pollice_Verso.jpg" height="2425" width="1630">
          <figcaption>2</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the aspect ratio to work on different screen size, one well known technic is to add a padding-top to your the div containing your image:

```
padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (divide 9 by 16 = 0.5625) */
```

Here, 56.25% is for a 16/9 ratio.

To make it work, your figure has to have a width set via a style attribute, any value, even a percentage. Then, the aspect ratio will be set thanks to the padding-top, keeping the right aspect ratio, whatever the width of the div. And if you use an image tag inside this figure tag, your image tag should have absolute position style. Or, you can set your image as a background-image, with a background-position: cover;

**But, if you have an API giving you the image url, its width and its height,** then, you could set a style attribute on the figure tag like this:

```
<figure style={{paddingTop: `${(height / width) * 100}%`}}>
```

and it will keep your aspect radio responsive, accordingly to your image aspect ratio calculated width its width and height

Comment: "you could set those values before the image display" this is what I'm trying to do but I don't manage to make it work responsively. I don't understand when you say "set those values on the parent `div`". First the parent is not a `div` but a `figure` . Second none of these elements have a width or height attribute.

Comment: Yes sorry I said div but it could be a figure or any other tag. If you know the width and height of the image before loading it, then your padding-top applied to your figure tag will be: (width / height) * 100. And you will set this value on your figure tag like this: <figure style={{paddingTop: ` ${ (width / height) * 100}% ` } } . That way, you will keep your image aspect ratio responsive and accordingly to your image :)

Comment: In that case it should be `height / width * 100`. That should work if I used the actual image but not for the placeholder which either displays the full size of the image or just a small square.